# C# getting pixels in picturebox with cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox, mouse-cursor

How can I get pixel `x` and `y` in a picturebox using the cursor?

Comment: Cast its Image property back to Bitmap and use GetPixel().

Comment: Do you mean the color of the pixel under the mouse pointer?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to get the color of the clicked pixel:

```
Color pixelColor;

// add the mouse click event handler in designer mode or:
// myPicturebox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(myPicturebox_MouseClick);
private void myPicturebox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
      pixelColor = GetColorAt(e.Location);
}

private Color GetColorAt(Point point) {
   return ((Bitmap)myPicturebox.Image).GetPixel(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind: the e.location is the location in the pictureBox whereas the real image is resized to fit into the box but still has its original size. When asking for the pixelvalue in this Image you get the value out of the unscaled image. This is (maybe) not the color value you might expect!

Answer (score 5):

The picture box has no way of getting the pixel.  But the image it contains can be used to create a [bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) object that has a getpixel function.  I would mention however that this is not the fastest of operations.  If you need it to be quick I would look to the GDI win32 functions.

Comment: That's the way I had to do it as I been using the graphics object to draw on the picturebox.  I render the complete image and then use GetPixel(x,y);